# IComparer not sorting simple a b c?

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparer

I have my String class setup and made a `StringComparer` class which implements `IComparer` and want to sort my strings array on `Rank` and display it. Currently it displays:

> a,x,c

when I sort on `Rank`. Why is this happening? It should display:

> a,c,x

Or has the alphabet changed overnight?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] strings = { new String() { Name = "1123", Rank = "a" }, new String() { Name = "3123", Rank = "x" }, new String() { Name = "3134311", Rank = "c" } };
        StringComparer comparer = new StringComparer();

        comparer.SortBy = StringComparer.CompareField.Name;
        Array.Sort(strings, comparer);

        foreach (String s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        }
        comparer.SortBy = StringComparer.CompareField.Rank;
        Array.Sort(strings, comparer);

        foreach (String s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Rank);
        }
    }
}

class String
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
}

class StringComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    public enum CompareField
    {
        Name,
        Rank
    }

    public CompareField SortBy = CompareField.Name;

    public int Compare(String x, String y)
    {
        switch (SortBy)
        {
            case CompareField.Name:
                return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
            case CompareField.Rank:
                return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Rank);
        }
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: It's better to create separate comparers for Rank and Name instead of having it done in a single class and having a enum to differentiate.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you don't have a class called `String`.

Comment: Wai Ha Lee: dont worry its just an example! :D

Comment: Sriram why would that be better? It requiers lots more code to write.. This would be true is you only use IComparable I guess

Comment: @TerryvandenBerg if you're going to use not writing more code as an argument, the counter-argument would be why write a custom comparer at all when the framework already provides several? See [`StringComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing

```
x.Name.CompareTo(y.Rank)
```

(comparing name to rank)

instead of

```
x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank)
```

(comparing rank to rank)

Comment: copy/paste/modify/oops ;)